# Deploying Grails app inside another Java EE web app as ONE war file

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails

I have existing Java EE web applications. And I also have a new Grails 1.3.7 application.

The requirement is to embedded this Grails app inside an existing Java EE app and deploy it in one war file. Please let me know if that would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the existing Java EE application is really tiny, I would say that is impossible and troublesome. Maybe, with a lot of work you might be able to have the two co-exist for a day or two, but then classpath and servlet-mapping conflicts are going to get the better of you.

Also, it will will severely impede your development process, the two apps will just get in the way of eachother; suddenly each grails command you execute is destroying the old Java EE app etc etc.

My advice: just don't do this, and find a different way of integrating the two.